# Estimate prevalence of ʻOumuamua-style interstellar obects inside Jupiter orbit now that C/2019 Q4 (Borisov) is found?

Tags: solar-system, interstellar, modeling

Now we know two of them, so maybe it's not an outlier.

We have two points so we can draw a line. How many similar macroscopic objects should be zipping through space at ~30 km/sec so that we would see one of these passing inside the orbit of Jupiter once every two years? I don't really know what units this should be expressed with. Maybe it's `1 / (km^2 * year)`  - the frequency of such a body coming through any random square kilometer of empty space in a year of time.

What's the "capture cross section" of intra-Jupiter orbit? I imagine that since the Sun affects trajectories of bodies coming near it, drawing them closer as they pass by, intra-Jupiter orbit will see much more bodies than a circle of same area in empty space. How large is this effect for ʻOumuamua-like bodies? I expect this is to be a unitless coefficient. Is it neligible? Is it 5x? 10x? 1000x?

Sorry if my question is not clear enough.

Comment: List of Hyperbolic comets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hyperbolic_comets (those with eccentricity >1)

Comment: Most of those are *barely* hyperbolic because of gravitation perturbances inside Solar system. They, in turn, may become scouts if they ever arrive to other systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The enhancement of a cross-section due to gravitational focusing is given by
$$ \sigma_{\rm eff} = \pi a_J^2 \left(1 + \frac{2GM_{\odot}}{a_J\ v^2}\right),$$
where  $a_J$ is the semi-major axis of Jupiter's orbit (assumed circular), $v$ is the relative velocity (at infinity) and I have ignored the mass of Jupiter.

Thus, using $v=30$ km/s (as specified in the question) the term in brackets is the gravitational focusing enhancement of the cross-section and equals 1.38.

We now assume an isotropic velocity distribution and a homogeneous density of such objects of $n$ per unit volume. The flux of such particles is $f =n v \sigma_{\rm eff}$.

If $f = 0.5$ yr$^{-1}$, then $n \sim 5 \times 10^{12}$ per cubic parsec.

Comment: Thank you for backing me up with math! I wonder how much error I had in my napkin calculations.

Answer (score 1):

I had to write my own code to calculate this, since I could not find any tools to solve two-body problem.

From my simulation it seems that Jupiter orbit cross section is `6.5 AU`, assuming radius of Jupiter orbit as `5 AU`. Seems like a tiny difference, but surface-wise it's `1.7x` increase. This assuming `20 km/s`, it's smaller for faster scouts.

This means one scout passes through a `6×10^24 square meters` per year. Thus we can expect 30 million of these passing through every square light year.

During that year, scout will travel at least `600 million km`. This means there's maybe `2×10^24` scouts in our galaxy.

Each scout probably weighs `2×10^9 kg`. This means there are `4×10^33 kg` worth of them in our galaxy. That's 2,000 suns.